# Failed to start Elastic Beanstlk

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, yaml, config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying my first Elastic Beanstalk configuration, and it failed
That's what I did:

```
mkdir .ebextensions
vi 01installation.config
```

Config:

```
packages:
    apt:
        apache2: []
        libapache2-mod-wsgi: []
        git: []
        apache2-threaded-dev: []

commands:
  01_download_apache_mod_dumpost:
      command: sudo git clone https://github.com/danghvu/mod_dumpost.git
  02_command:
      command: alias apxs2=apxs
  03_change_log_level:
      command: sudo sed -i 's/LogLevel warn/LogLevel debug/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
  04a_install_mod_dumpost:
      command: sudo make
  04b_install_mod_dumpost:
      command: sudo make install
```

Next I downloaded `AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-CLI` and created an alias eb:

```
alias eb="python2.7 ~/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python2.7/eb"
```

Than in my working directory did:

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "Initital setup"
```

Than did:

```
eb init
eb start
```

After I answered all question in CLI, I got this:

```
Waiting for environment "workerbeanstalk-env" to launch.
2013-07-31 10:25:27 INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2013-07-31 10:25:33 INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-xxxxxxxxxxx as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2013-07-31 10:25:52 INFO    Created load balancer named: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2013-07-31 10:26:13 INFO    Created security group named: xxxxxxxxxxx4
2013-07-31 10:26:17 INFO    Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2013-07-31 10:27:15 INFO    Created Auto Scaling group named: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2013-07-31 10:27:15 INFO    Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
2013-07-31 10:27:19 INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:scalingPolicy:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:autoScalingGroupName/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-xxxxxxxxxxxxx:policyName/xxxxxxxxxxxxk-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-xxxxxxxxx
2013-07-31 10:27:19 INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:scalingPolicy:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:autoScalingGroupName/xxxxxxxxxx-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroupxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:policyName/awseb-xxxxxxxxxxx-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2013-07-31 10:27:23 INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awsebxxxxxxxxxx-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-xxxxxxxxxxxx
2013-07-31 10:27:23 INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-xxxxxxxxxxk-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2013-07-31 10:29:32 ERROR   Responses from [i-32xxxxx3] were received, but the commands failed.
2013-07-31 10:30:39 INFO    Successfully launched environment: workerbeanstalk-env
```

The last line shows that it launched, but Helath check shown in RED. 
I tried to SSH into instance to check what have been installed or downloaded, but had no luck obviously, because I didnt provide a key-pair, (if someone could help me figure out where to specify key-pair would be great too)
So the main question what I did wrong, and why it doesn't launching?

Comment: your question sounds like my own problem recently. I posted the question and then later found the answer, and I hope it answers your questions as well. View the post at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710587/aws-ec2-key-pair-setup

Answer (score 1):

Re your question - *if someone could help me figure out where to specify key-pair would be great too*

As you are using Elastic Beanstalk, the easiest way is via the EBS console - "Configuration" screen.

Under the settings for "Instances" (click the gear wheel on the right), there's the field "EC2 Key pair".
If there are none listed, you have to create a pair in the EC2 menu - Network & Security -> Key pairs

Comment: is it possible through the eb cli?

Comment: The question was about the CLI, and the CLI is pretty useless if you still have to go to the website to configure random things.