# AWS EC2 Key Pair setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, key-pair

I'm trying to setup my AWS EC2 Instance with a Key Pair that I just created.  The original instance was already setup without a key pair, so I'm trying to Launch a new Instance and set the Key Pair during that process.  AWS docs instruct to "Specify the new key pair that you created" after I select the AMI, but I do not see anywhere that I can do this during the creation process.  So, either I'm really clueless or something is not showing up correctly in the AWS creation steps (probably the former).

Instance: t1.micro

AMI: Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09

Ports: 80 and 22

Forgive me if I'm not including all the appropriate details.  I'm brand new to AWS and nothing is coming easily for me.  I have researched this to death here on SO and on Google to no avail.

Comment: If you only have one key configured with AWS, I believe it will select that automatically.

Comment: In the Instance details, the Key pair name shows as "-".  Wouldn't that indicate that nothing is selected?  Or, are you suggesting that it's simply implied...

Comment: With a linux instance, you need to have a keypair configured or you wont bel able to access the instance. I presume that if you can launch the instance without selecting the keypair, then its defaulting to or creating a keypair at launch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the two comments above.  Unfortunately, neither address the issue as I was needing addressed.

I did find the following AWS documentation, which is specifically noted by AWS as "Computing Basics for Windows", but in bullet pt# 4 of this "Step 4: Launch an Instance" page there is the clarification that you must first press LAUNCH before the Key Pair setting is requested of you.  Nowhere else in their documentation was this specified, which was the confusion for me: I didn't want to press LAUNCH without first selecting the Key Pair but in fact that's a required step.  Here's the URL:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/computebasics/gettingstarted-launch-instance.html

I hope this clarifies confusion for someone else in the future.

Comment: This is a recent change to the launch wizard.  Unfortunately Amazon has not updated their Getting Started documentation to reflect this.